I (noob) just installed ubuntu to a 2013ish intel imac. The sound is either loud or muted. The numbers move on volume control but no change till muted
I just installed Ubuntu. I originally had no sound but when I went to the sound settings, I found the option of 2 output devices: Speakers-Built-in Audio and Digital Output (S/PDIF) Built-in Audio.
When I select Speakers-Built-in Audio I have the option of 3 Configurations: Analog Stereo Output, Analog Surround 2.1 Output, and Analog Surround 4.0 output. I DO have sound when I use the two surround sound outputs however it is loud and one volume. The volume buttons do make the volume thing show up on display and the number goes up and down but no change until you get to 0 when it goes mute. The slider in the sound settings also does not do anything.
I did an LSPCI in terminal and here is what shows up.
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev e4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev e4)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4360 802.11ac Dual Band Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM57766 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe (rev 01)
03:00.1 SD Host controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM57765/57785 SDXC/MMC Card Reader (rev 01)
04:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL4510 Thunderbolt Bridge [Redwood Ridge 4C 2013]
05:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL4510 Thunderbolt Bridge [Redwood Ridge 4C 2013]
05:03.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL4510 Thunderbolt Bridge [Redwood Ridge 4C 2013]
05:04.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL4510 Thunderbolt Bridge [Redwood Ridge 4C 2013]
05:05.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL4510 Thunderbolt Bridge [Redwood Ridge 4C 2013]
05:06.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL4510 Thunderbolt Bridge [Redwood Ridge 4C 2013]
06:00.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation DSL4510 Thunderbolt NHI [Redwood Ridge 4C 2013]

I have done some research and was in alsamixer whilst I was in linuxmint but I thought I messed everything up and decided I wanted to try ubuntu instead so just did a fresh install. The only thing I have modified was downloading a driver for the broadcom wifi to work.
Thank you for any help.
P.S. this Ubuntu 24.04.1 if that matters.

FYI:  Your mention of Linux Mint is of little value; as you didn't provide the essential stack details (ie. release); as PulseAudio was replaced with PipeWire in mid-late 2022 (23.04 for some flavors, 22.10 for rest); and thus your older Linux Mint setup may have used a much older [different] stack than the 2024-April release you installed.

it was linuxmint newest one I installed it the day before I just installed ubuntu. I found something if I go in sound settings i can system sound and firefox sound (youtube) and when I move that slider the sound levels do change but the volume keys and any other slider dont do anything. Is there a way to get the volume keys on keyboard to control that slider.

Linux Mint have two different products; one based on Ubuntu & the other based on Debian... You need to be clear and specific with details for them to be useful; but I'll suggest comparing the software stack & configuration details of your Linux Mint tested system with your Ubuntu system for clues; if you used the Ubuntu based version particularly that would reveal quite a lot of helpful detail & likely solution to fix your issue; but we're limited if only given vague details.
